# Cardinality of a Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Theorem: For every Hausdorff space $X$, $|X|\leq [d(X)]^{\chi(X)}$.

Engelking's proof starts as follows:

Suppose we have a neighborhood system $\{B(x)\}_{x\in X}$ such that $|B(x)|\leq\chi(X)$ for all $x\in X$ and that $\chi(X)$ is infinite.

Denote by $A_0$ the family of all subsets of $A$ with cardinality less (or equal to) than $\chi(X)$. Obviously, $|A_0|\leq [d(X)]^{\chi(X)}$.

For every $U$ in $B(x)$ we choose a point $a(x,U)\in U\cap A_0$ and consider the set $A(x)=\{a(x,U) ; U\in B(x)\}\in A_0$.

Here, I have continued the proof, as opposed to Engelking, that the function that maps to each $x$ in $X$ its corresponding $A(x)$ is an injective function, establishing the proof of the theorem. However, Engelking makes the proof more complicated, as it seems to me, superfluously.

Is my proof faulty?

Comment: How does your "proof" go that $A(x) = A(y)$ implies $x=y$, just from Hausdorffness?. You have no control over how the $a(x,U)$ were chosen. We choose them once at the start. I see no reason why different points $x$ need to have different sets $A(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some minor corrections concerning Engelking's proof:

- you forgot to mention that $A$ is a dense subset of $X$ with cardinality $d(X)$,
- point $a(x,U)$ is taken from $U\cap A$, not $U\cap A_0$.

I think that the mapping $x\mapsto A(x)$, as defined above, need not to be injective. Here is an example. Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a Hausdorff space with more than one point such that the character of each point equals $\left|\mathcal{O}\right|$, for example, $X=I^I$ with the product topology. Then it may happen that for any $x$, $B(x)$ consists of all open neighbourhoods of $x$. It may also happen that for some distinct points $x,y\in A$ and for all $U\in B(x)$, $a(x,U)=y$ if $y\in U$ and $a(x,U)=x$ otherwise, similarly for all $V\in B(y)$, $a(y,V)=x$ if $x\in V$ and $a(y,V)=y$ otherwise. Then $A(x)=A(y)=\{x,y\}$, so $x\mapsto A(x)$ is not injective.

Comment: I am sorry that I have taken so long to reply, but I was busy. Thanks for showing my proof is faulty (after revising it, I discovered the proof in my logic). I appreciate the answer and it shows me the fault in my intuition that led to a faulty proof (Proof was faulty because at some step I relied on intuition rather than pure logic)

Comment: @HasanSaad You are welcome.